# What's the best way to call callbacks passed into a Redux subapp?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, redux-thunk

I'm following the Redux "subapp" pattern [described here](https://redux.js.org/recipes/isolating-subapps), but I'm having a little trouble figuring out the best way to call callbacks passed into the subapp, especially in response to asynchronous actions.

Here's an inelegant but working solution: https://jsfiddle.net/jochakovsky/bgx86m6j/. I'm not a big fan of this approach - it forces me to pass the callback further down than I'd like, into `ReduxSubappView`, which shouldn't have to know anything about that callback. The most natural place to call the callback is the async action creator `initialize`, but it does not have access to the props passed into `ReduxSubApp`. Also, it feels weird to compare props and nextProps - presentational components should really only be responsible for converting the current props into a UI, and not have to understand state transitions. Additionally, `ReduxSubappView` cannot be a pure functional component with this approach.

What's the best way to handle this type of situation?

Comment: I think the point of using sub apps is to isolate them, since they don't care about each other. To accomplish what you want, I wouldn't pass any callback. Instead, you can get the sub app to dispatch an action when they're initialized. This action sets a flag in the state and then the top app listen for the changes and react to them.

Comment: @RafaelRozon, I'm working within a decomposed front-end architecture where each subapp is coded independently and just has to adhere to a certain API. Each subapp can be architected in any way - Redux is just an implementation detail, if it makes sense for a particular subapp. I can't really change the API or add an app-level Redux store.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to pass down props from the Subapp root level *and* you can't use redux in all Subapps, you would need a global pub/sub or something comparable to subscribe to changes.

Here's a native approach with `addEventListener`:

```
// in Subapp:
document.addEventListener('initialized', function(e){console.log('app initialized')});

// Wherever the event originates from:
document.dispatchEvent(new Event('initialized'));
```

A dedicated library might be better, since this has the events bubbling through the DOM (for no reason really), but it should work out of the box.